# Sum of the series $\sum_{i=1}^n\ (n+1-i)^i \\ $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the sum of $\sum_{i=1}^n  (n+1-i)^i  $

The series also can be represented as $\sum_{i=1}^n i^{n+1-i} $

It seems like a very difficult nut to crack. Attempting this has taught me a lot about other series but I have made no real headway here.

I considered manipulating
$S = n^1+(n-1)^2+...+1^n$
$S-(1+n)=(n-1)^2+...+2^{n-1}$
$n*S=n^2+n[(n-1)^2+...+2^{n-1}]+n$
$n*S=n^2+n[S-(1+n)]+n$
$n*S=n*S$

Comment: Any particular reason you think the sum has a closed form?

Comment: Mathematica doesn't know a closed form. It grows approximately exponentially with $n$.

Comment: OEIS has only a recursive continued fraction for this: https://oeis.org/A003101

Comment: Maybe the sum does not have a closed form but the curious side of me won't sleep (quite literally for the past few nights) until I try it in various ways.

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer, but it would be too long for a comment**

Basically your series, if we take the very first terms, is:

$$n + (n-1)^2 + (n-2)^3 + (n-3)^4 + \cdots $$

And we can write it also in this easier way:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^N (N-k)^{k+1} = \sum_{k = 0}^N (N-k)^k\cdot (N-k)$$

*I checked with Mathematica and it doesn't spit out anything.. So I don't think a close form does exist.*

Eventually we may split the two sum as

$$N\ \sum_{k = 0}^N (N-k)^{k} - \sum_{k = 0}^N k(N-k)^k$$

But no close forms do exist also for these ones.
You may try to evaluate some terms or to take some tries with respect to a chosen $N$. Probably a close form does not exist because it's a too irregular series.

However, the very fist computation for the series $S$ are (may be useful for you or someone else):

$$N = 2 ~~~ \to ~~~ S = 3$$

$$N = 3 ~~~ \to ~~~ S = 8$$

$$N = 4 ~~~ \to ~~~ S = 22$$

$$N = 5 ~~~ \to ~~~ S = 65$$

$$N = 6 ~~~ \to ~~~ S = 209$$

$$N = 7 ~~~ \to ~~~ S = 732$$

$$N = 8 ~~~ \to ~~~ S = 2780$$

$$N = 9 ~~~ \to ~~~ S = 11377$$

$$N = 10 ~~~ \to ~~~ S = 49863$$

Notice that the $N-th$ coefficient will always be zero, indeed it is

$$(N-N)^{N+1} = 0^{N+1}$$

Whilst the $(n-1)$-th coefficient will always be one:

$$(N - (N-1))^{N-1+1} = 1^N$$

And the $(N-2)$-th coefficient will be

$$(N - (N-2))^{N-2+1} = 2^{N-1}$$

And so on..

Comment: That is very good. I like how you split the sum into two.

Comment: You're welcome! I hope it was somehow helpful, but I?m sorry I couldn't do more.. :/